# Updating field from the name in another Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two tables:

```
tbl_courses
id  user_id  course_name
3   5        First Course
4   5        Second Course


tbl_notes
id  user_id  course_id
1   5        3
2   5        4
```

I am trying to write a simple merge script that is receiving an updated course title: `course_name`

For example, the user changed `First Course` to be `Second Course` and has requested that the all the notes with this new title be merged into this one.

So I am trying to find a way to update all the entries in `tbl_notes` with course_id from `First Course` to match the id of `Second Course`

I am sending `$user_id`, `$course_id`, and `$course_name` as parameters

Comment: you mean where course_id=3 update it to 4?

Comment: Yeah, but there could be many notes with that course_id.  This was just a short example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correct understand there is query what you need:

**[SQLFiddleexample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a14ae/1)**

```
    UPDATE `tbl_notes`
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_courses` 
      ON `tbl_courses`.`user_id`  =`tbl_notes`.`user_id`
        AND `tbl_courses`.id  = `tbl_notes`.`course_id`
    SET `tbl_notes`.`course_id` = 4
    WHERE `tbl_courses`.`course_name` ='First Course'
      AND `tbl_courses`.`user_id` = 5
```

With PHP code SQL query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `tbl_notes`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_courses` 
  ON `tbl_courses`.`user_id`  =`tbl_notes`.`user_id`
    AND `tbl_courses`.id  = `tbl_notes`.`course_id`
SET `tbl_notes`.`course_id` = $course_id
WHERE `tbl_courses`.`course_name` ='First Course'
AND `tbl_courses`.`user_id` =$user_id ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update tbl_notes set course_id=(select id  
from tbl_courses where course_name='First Course' limit 1)
```